# How to create luatex.fmt

Tags: luatex, format-files

I wanted to try the latest version of LuaTeX, so I downloaded the [official precompiled binaries](http://www.luatex.org/download.html) but these raw binaries are useless without a `luatex.fmt`. How can this file be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have TeX Live installed, so will have the file 'luatex.ini'. You need that (*i.e.* copy to where you are going to generate your format file), as it specifies how to build the format. You should then be able to do

```
luatex -ini luatex.ini
```

to build the format file.

Comment: I lately had some problems with this solution and solved the issue by running fmtutil --all.